# Dynamically generating listbox data from website, windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, web, listbox, dynamic-data

I am about to begin a major step in my app by taking images I post on my website and having the phone retrieve these images and dynamically add them to a listbox. That listbox will contain a thumbnail of the image, as well as the time it was posted. If a user clicks on the image, they will be taken to another page where they can either download it to the phone or share it to someone.

However, as with any absolute beginner, I am seeking tutorials on how to do this.

I have found two:

> http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/18/building-a-windows-phone-7-twitter-application-using-silverlight.aspx
>
> [Windows Phone 7: Making ListBox items change dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358495/windows-phone-7-making-listbox-items-change-dynamically)

I'll make some mock code up in an effort to help understand my approach on this:

1. Have a listbox (name: photosfromsite)
2. Aim is to have ListBoxItems as individual photos from the site. How to populate these  dynamically is yet to be done. How?
3. Be able to pass ListBoxItem name/identifier/etc to pass the image on new page when
   clicked (use query during page transition?)
4. Have website set with photos.
5. Do an asynch call upon application launch to retrieve these images.Calling maybe 10 at 
   a time?

Page1 XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="layoutgrid">
  <StackPanel x:Name="panelforlistbox">
     <ListBox x:Name="photosfromsite">
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

             <ListBoxItem>
             <Image Source="http://www.thewebsite.com/Image1.jpg>
             </ListBoxItem>

             <ListBoxItem>
             <Image Source="http://www.thewebsite.com/Image2.jpg>
             </ListBoxItem>

             ......
             ......

          </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Page1 C#:

```
//Some event handler to requisition the website for the images placed

//Some code to grab {get, set} the date and time

//Some code to generate a new listbox item in light of this.

//Some event handler for getting the updated list, if not already updated.

//Some event handler to signify when a user clicked on a listboxitem and to 
//pull that info to a new page.
```

I realize I am missing a large portion of this code, but I think I have a somewhat passable framework in mind of what I need to do?

Any help is always appreciated. I've picked up C# for the first time a couple months ago, and slowly I've been learning a lot about it. This seems to be the only major thing in my way before my app is done, and I just want to make sure I get it right!

And to make sure no ambiguity exists in the claim about what my question is -- Are these suitable tutorials or is there somewhere with a step-by-step instruction (preferably video) of how to accomplish exactly what I am trying to do. If not, can example code be written or pasted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered how the website will maintain a list of its images? Or are you going to *scrape* the HTML for them?

Are they going to be FTP'd to the site or will there be some form of DB that contains a list of them?

A webservice could then be added to the site that returns a list of all images that would then be the datasource of the list box. A convertor could be used to modify the image file name to include the full path to where the image is? I'm guessing the webservice could even be used to create the thumbnails and send them to the phone, or the phone could retrieve them and create the thumbnail.

It would be worth considering the bandwidth requirements of moving large images images about.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jason. I have not considered any of it as I don't even know what my options are. Quite literally, I am in the dark on this.  I would like my website to function like icanhascheezburger.com, where it's a blog-like website, the webmaster puts photos on the frontpage, and they magically get pulled into the application on the phone. What would be simpler to do, both in the short and longrun, for FTP or a DB of a list? I can upload them through dreamweaver to my FTP without a problem, but would that become an enormous task in say a year from now?

Comment: As for bandwith, the site I have claims unlimited bandwith. However, I don't expect the images to be larger than 50kb, as I will manually resize the user submitted ones.

Comment: How would I go about adding a webservice too?

Comment: Been out all day today.  I'll try and get some stuff to you later or tomorrow.

Comment: Hmmm. That's a lot to cover. I suggest that you look at breaking the problem down into 1. SQL database to include a table that holds the name/path and possibly description of the file that will be uploaded. 2. A way of using the asp.net upload contol in an asp.net web page to pull the image from the local file system to the web server. 3. A way to create a new record in the database when a new file is uploaded. 4. A .net web service (.asmx/.svc) page that exposes methods to provide a list of the images (maybe is selection criteria or genre,etc.) and a way to retrieve a path or list of paths.

Comment: This is a fantastic tutorial where I learnt an enormous amount of asp.net a database access. It won't provide all of the answers to what you are trying to do but it will hopefully contain enough to allow you to create the web element of your requirements.

[ASP.NET database tutorial](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs)

Please come back to me if you have any other questions.